# How to get Network Analyst data from script file back into Model Builder?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I am running a script which takes some input parameters and runs some Network Analyst processes. The script is imported into a toolbox and is setup in Model Builder with the necessary input and output parameters.

My problem is that I am struggling to understand how to get the resulting Solve operation back out of the script and into Model Builder for subsequent work.

Here is my script:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

# Script arguments
Network_Dataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # Network dataset layer

Input_Locations = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # Layer file

Output_Path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # Output path

# Local variables:
#Solve_Succeeded = Network_Analyst_Layer__3_
#Output_derived_feature_class = Network_Dataset

arcpy.AddMessage("Creating the Origin Destination layer...")

# Process: Make OD Cost Matrix Layer
arcpy.MakeODCostMatrixLayer_na(Network_Dataset, "odMatrix", "Length", "100", "", "", "ALLOW_UTURNS", "", "", "", "NO_LINES", "")

arcpy.AddMessage("Calculating Locations. This may take a while...")

# Process: Calculate Locations
arcpy.CalculateLocations_na(Input_Locations, Network_Dataset, "500 Meters", [["Streets","SHAPE"],["Streets_ND_Junctions","NONE"]] , "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "INCLUDE", "")

arcpy.AddMessage("Adding locations to Origin Destination layer...")

# Process: Add Locations to Origins Sub-Layer
arcpy.AddLocations_na("odMatrix", "Origins", Input_Locations, "", "500 Meters", "", "", "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "APPEND", "", "", "INCLUDE", "")

# Process: Add Locations to Destinations Sub-Layer
arcpy.AddLocations_na("odMatrix", "Destinations", Input_Locations, "", "500 Meters", "", "", "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "APPEND", "", "", "INCLUDE", "")

arcpy.AddMessage("Starting Network Analysis solve...")

# Process: Solve
arcpy.Solve_na("odMatrix", "SKIP", "TERMINATE", "")

arcpy.AddMessage("Network analysis completed.")

# How to get this out of script???

# Return as model output parameter
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(3, outputTable)
```

Comment: Pity you are on 10.0. In 10.1 and above, you could use: naClasses = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(serviceAreaLayer) >> arcpy.na.Solve(serviceAreaLayer) >>
polygonsSublayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(serviceAreaLayer,naClasses["SAPolygons"])[0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the result as a layer filer with this command

`arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile("odMatrix",Output_Path)`

after : `arcpy.Solve_na("odMatrix", "SKIP", "TERMINATE", "")`

where Output_Path must be the path to a lyr file.

we can find more informations here :

http://resources.arcgis.com/fr/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00480000000r000000